# How to merge only rows which meet a certain condition in two dataframes in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge two dataframes by a common column, only matching rows which meet a certain criteria in another column:

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var1" = c(1,2,1,2,2))

df2 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var2" = c(121,334,565,77,12))
```

I want to merge df2 into df1 based on id when var1=1, returning NA for non matches. So it should look like:

```
df3 <- data.frame("id" = c("1001","1002","1003", "1004", "1005"),
                  "var1" = c(1,2,1,2,2),
                  "var2" = c(121,NA,565,NA,NA))
```

I can't find much guidance on this online

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a join and `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'id') %>% 
    mutate(var2 = replace(var2, var1 == 2, NA))
```

-output

```
    id var1 var2
1 1001    1  121
2 1002    2   NA
3 1003    1  565
4 1004    2   NA
5 1005    2   NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df2$var2[df2$id %in% df1$id[df1$var1 == 2]] <- NA
merge(df1, df2)
    id var1 var2
1 1001    1  121
2 1002    2   NA
3 1003    1  565
4 1004    2   NA
5 1005    2   NA
```

Comment: Thank you! These are all helpful suggestions, but went with this one

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)

merge(df1, df2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1==1, var2, NA_real_))

    id var1 var2
1 1001    1  121
2 1002    2   NA
3 1003    1  565
4 1004    2   NA
5 1005    2   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use the base function merge and then store NA values where var1 *doesn't* meet you criterion, like follows:

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by = "id")

df3$var2[df3$var1 != 1] <- NA
```

If your actual data is more complicated, this may not scale up as well.